# Animate the images while they are scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have written a small div slider which scrolls images put in the div after every 5 secs and also there are two arrows on the side that trigger the sliding immediately. well this is not important, when the images slide towards their left or right or whenever they slide automatically I want there to be some kind of animation happening on the images like fading or cutting instead of just sliding.

**Javascript code:**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            function createSlider(el_left, el_right, items) {
    var index = 0;
                var refreshId;
                var items=$('.box');
                var restartAnimation = function() {
                    clearInterval(refreshId);
                    refreshId = setInterval( function() 
                    {    
                        var $this = items.eq(index);
        $this.animate({
            left: '-50%'
        }, 500);
        index = (index + 1) % items.length;
        var $next = items.eq(index);
        $next.css('left', '150%');
        $next.animate({
            left: '50%'
        }, 500);
                    },5000);
                }

                restartAnimation()

    el_left.click(function() {
                    restartAnimation();
        var $this = items.eq(index);
        $this.animate({
            left: '-50%'
        }, 500);
        index = (index + 1) % items.length;
        var $next = items.eq(index);
        $next.css('left', '150%');
        $next.animate({
            left: '50%'
        }, 500);
    });
    el_right.click(function() {
        restartAnimation();
        var $this = items.eq(index);
        $this.animate({
            left: '150%'
        }, 500);
        index = (index - 1) % items.length;
        var $next = items.eq(index);
        $next.css('left', '-50%');
        $next.animate({
            left: '50%'
        }, 500);
    });
}

createSlider($('.Animate'), $('.Animate2'), $('.box'))
        </script>
```

**HTML code:**

```
        <div id="container" class="imageSlider">

          <div id="box1" class="box"><img style="height: 190px;width: auto;vertical-align: middle;margin: 0px 50px 12px 0px;" src="images/image1.png" class="emages"></div>
          <div id="box2" class="box"><img style="height: 185px;width: auto;vertical-align: middle;" src="images/image2.png" class="emages"></div>
          <div id="box3" class="box"><img style="height:264px;margin-top:0px;margin-left: 200px;width:auto;" src="images/image3.png" class="emages"></div>
          <div id="box4" class="box"><img style="height: 265px;width: auto;vertical-align: middle;margin: 51px 60px 0 -31px;" src="images/image4.png" class="emages"></div>
          <div id="box5" class="box"><img style="height: 194px;width: auto;vertical-align: middle;" src="images/image5.png" class="emages"></div>
          <div id="box6" class="box"><img style="height: 230px;width: auto;vertical-align: middle;margin: -50px 50px;" src="images/image6.png" class="emages"></div>
          <div id="box7" class="box"><img style="height: 230px;width: auto;vertical-align: middle;margin: -50px 50px;" src="images/image7.png" class="emages"></div>

     <div><input type="image" id="animate1"  src="nav-left.png" class="Animate"></div>
     <div><input type="image" id="animate2" src="nav-right.png" class="Animate2"></div>

</div>
```

**CSS code:**

```
#container {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 120px auto;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 700px;
    height: 350px;
    overflow: hidden;
    left: 24%;

}

.box {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    line-height: 300px;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;    
    left: 150%;
    top: 84px;
    margin-left: -48%;
    color: white;
}

#box1 {

    left: 50%;
}

#box2 {

}

#box3 {

}

#box4 {

}

#box5 {

}
#box6 {

}
#box7{

}
```

So this is my complete code. And it is working properly, only thing I want is that when the images scroll I want them to scroll in style or with some animation.

Comment: @ryadavilli Sorry did not understand..

Comment: @mr_app Can you give one example in the comment box or as an answer with respect to the code posted above.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:

1) Add a classes to handle fade to your CSS

```
.fade-in {
opacity: 1;
transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
}

.fade-out {
opacity: 0;
transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
}
```

2) And then in your code add/remove the classes at the appropriate place, for example:

```
$this.removeClass('fade-in');
$this.addClass('fade-out');

$next.removeClass('fade-out');
$next.addClass('fade-in');
```

Comment: If you could please provide web accessible URL's to your images I would be happy to give it a go in jsfiddle.

Comment: Hey bro I have made a rough jsfiddle for you, http://jsfiddle.net/ykbgT/4627/ The images are not there but its functioning well even if you click on the missing image icon.